# Unittest Passing arguments from another script

Tags: python, unit-testing, arguments

So here is a pretty simple script im running from an webservice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

test=int(sys.argv[1])+int(sys.argv[2])
print(test)
```

and now I want to write an Unittest script to test this script, but I dont know how I should pass the 2 required arguments inside a unittest function. Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unittest
import ExecuteExternal

class TestUnittest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
       self.assertTrue(ExecuteExternal, "5", "5"==10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I did search here in the forum but was not able to find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrangle the sys args but the preferred way is to wrap your logic in a function, and put the typical **main** check around the function call in your script.

Them you can import the script in your unit test and call the function instead of ruining the script.

This is an untested version of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

def calc(a, b):
    return int(a)+int(b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calc(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

assuming your script is called ExecuteExternal.py then your test script goes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unittest
import ExecuteExternal

class TestUnittest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        result = ExecuteExternal.calc("5", "6")
        self.assertTrue(result, 11)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: My main problem is that the script is called by my webservice with some arguments and if I include the unittest within the script itselve unittest gives me 2 errors which are like: module "__main__" has no attribute: "argument1" and the same for the second argument

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore you should watch your naming convention for the script. See PEP8 at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names